# how to navigate between two stack navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
const App=() => {
  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NativeBaseProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='home' component={Home}/>
           
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
      
    </Provider>
  );
};



const Deshboard = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={DashboardHomeScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="ProfileStack"
          component={ProfileStack}
          options={{headerShown: false, tabBarLabel: 'Setting'}}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

when i am logout account then go to  parent stack of login page that not happend and show me a error

```
const logout1 = async (dispatch, navigation) => {
  dispatch(logout(navigation));
  navigation.navigate("login");
};
```

i want a go to DashboardHomeScreen to login page.
both are diffrent stack

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [React Navigation documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation) for the useNavigation hook.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Then in your App, write this

```
const App=() => {

    const Navigation = useNavigation(); 
    ...
}
```

Lastly, rewrite your logout1 function as:

```
const logout1 = async (dispatch, navigation) => {
  dispatch(logout(navigation));
  Navigation.navigate("login"); //check this
};
```